# FileNet P8 ver 5.0: Deleting Bulk Documents

Tags: bulk, filenet-p8, filenet

### Below are our Requirement

One of the Application (say ABC) Uses FileNet only to Store documents. Now some of those references got purged in ABC (But the purged documents Ids are store in ABC's DB ) and those documents store inside FileNet are no more required and need to be deleted to clean up space.

To achieve the above we have the following logic:

1. Grab the Document Ids from ABS's DB
2. Run the delete method inside CE

The Problem is how it is possible to connect to a different DB outside CE and also

1. Will Script inside Search be good option?
2. Using Batch Delete but problem, if one document fails than the whole
   process will fail and we have to return
3. Can these be possible using Custom Event and subscription?

Answer (score 1):

A simple custom batch processing Java/.NET program can serve that purpose. Also it will help in running it periodically if you are planning to have this activity scheduled every month/quarterly.

You can use below code snippet for reference. Its not optimum, of course, but just scribbled down.

```
String query = "select DOCID from ......."; //appropriate query to return document ids.
try{
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while(rs.next()){
        Document doc = Factory.Document.getInstance(os, ClassNames.DOCUMENT, new Id(<<doc Id in the loop>>));
        doc.delete();
        doc.save(RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH);
    }
} catch (SQLException e)
{
   //something went wrong with the sql
}
```

About custom Event, I am not sure which custom Event will you associate the trigger with?

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom DB from where i would get the GUID and then delete the document from CE if it is available. All the records associated with the GUID would be deleted from the table.

Also, the method is made synchronized to enable multiple threads to speed up the process. The batch delete definitely takes time as the number of records increase. The output message still needs to be arranged.

```
/**
 * This method "HARD" deletes the document from CE in <B>BATCH</B>.
 * @param filenetDocGUID
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static synchronized String batchDeleteDocumentFromCE_DB(List<String> filenetDocGUID, String QUERY) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Start of batchDeleteDocumentFromCE_DB() method");
    System.out.println("Input Parameter filenetDocGUID is : " + filenetDocGUID);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Document document = null;
    UserContext uc = null;
    ObjectStore os = null;
    Subject subject = null;
    VersionSeries vs = null;
    UpdatingBatch ub = null;

    int deletedRecordsFromDB [] = null ;
    List<String> deletedRecordsFromCE = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    String messageBody = "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\"><tr><td>GUID</td><td>DB Records</td><td>CE Records</td></tr>";
    List<String> processedfilenetDocGUID = null;

    try {
        if (filenetDocGUID != null) {

            getCESession(); // This will get CE Session

            os = ceSessionData.getObjectStore(); 
            System.out.println("Domain fetched from CESession static reference is : " + ceSessionData.getDomain());

            // The RefreshMode parameter indicates that the property cache for this instance is to be 
            // refreshed with the updated data.
            ub = UpdatingBatch.createUpdatingBatchInstance(ceSessionData.getDomain(), RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH);
            System.out.println("Batch update object created");

            subject = ceSessionData.getSubject();
            System.out.println("Subject fetched from CESession static reference.");

            uc = UserContext.get();
            uc.pushSubject(subject);

            dbConnection = getDataBaseConnection();
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false); // auto commit is set to false so that DB is not committed before deleting the records
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(QUERY);
            //QUERY will be for the db from where you need to remove the data
            deletedRecordsFromCE = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (os != null) 
            {
                processedfilenetDocGUID = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(String GUID : filenetDocGUID)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //get document versions from CE
                        document = Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os, GUID.trim(), null);
                        vs = document.get_VersionSeries();
                        vs.delete();
                        ub.add(vs, null);// add documents to the batch

                        //prepare statement for deleting records from DB with the GUID
                        preparedStatement.setString(1, GUID.trim());
                        preparedStatement.addBatch();   // add records to dB batch for deletion
                        deletedRecordsFromCE.add("1");

                        processedfilenetDocGUID.add(GUID);
                    }
                    catch(Exception exp)
                    {
                        if(exp.getMessage().contains("The requested item was not found.")||exp.getMessage().contains("E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND"))
                        {
                            log.error("The requested item with GUID : "+GUID.trim()+" was not found in CE.");
                            //If document is not available in CE, then delete all records associated with it from DB
                            //document not present in CE but available in DB so delete all the DB records referring to this GUID
                            //prepare statement for deleting records from DB with the GUID

                            preparedStatement.setString(1, GUID.trim());
                            preparedStatement.addBatch();
                            deletedRecordsFromCE.add("The requested item was not found.");

                            processedfilenetDocGUID.add(GUID);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            log.error("Exception occurred while fetching Document Version Series from DB");
                        }
                    }
                }

                deletedRecordsFromDB =  preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                System.out.println("Batch Records deleted from DB >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                if(ub.hasPendingExecute())
                {
                    //execute the batch only if there are records in the batch
                    ub.updateBatch();
                    System.out.println("Batch Records deleted from CE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("No records to be deleted from CE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                }

                dbConnection.commit();
                System.out.println("DB delete records commit successful");

                //below will create a html to view the report for deletion
                for(int i=0; i<processedfilenetDocGUID.size(); i++)
                {
                    messageBody = messageBody+("<tr><td>"+processedfilenetDocGUID.get(i)+"</td>");
                    if(deletedRecordsFromCE.get(i)!=null)
                    {
                        //only if document was present in CE or document version series was not obtained from CE
                        messageBody = messageBody+("<td>"+deletedRecordsFromDB[i]+"</td><td>"+deletedRecordsFromCE.get(i)+"</td>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if any other exception occurs then neglect the record and proceed with others
                        messageBody = messageBody+("<td>"+deletedRecordsFromDB[i]+"</td><td>Exception occured while deleting from CE.</td>");
                    }
                    messageBody = messageBody+(messageBody + "</tr>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in deleteDocumentFromCE() Method of CEManager.class");

        dbConnection.rollback(); // rollback from dB in case of issues
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception("System Error occurred while deleting the document in CE.. "+e.getMessage());
    }
    finally 
    {
        messageBody = messageBody+("<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Time taken for Batch in msec : "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)+"</td></tr>");
        messageBody = messageBody+("<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Records deleted : "+processedfilenetDocGUID.size()+" from input "+filenetDocGUID.size()+"</td></tr>");
        messageBody = messageBody+("</table>");

        System.out.println("Message : "+messageBody);
        document = null;
        vs = null;
        ub = null;
        deletedRecordsFromCE = null;
        closeDBResources(dbConnection, preparedStatement, null);
        if (uc != null)
            uc.popSubject();
    }

    System.out.println("End of batchDeleteDocumentFromCE_DB() method.");
    return messageBody;
}
```